# Write excel file as output from Flask app

Tags: python, excel, flask

I have this app on my company server that basically takes an image/pdf and outputs an excel file. I want to have it run on my friends computer who has no access to the server. Ideally he would give the image/pdf path and the title of the final excel file as inputs and get an excel file immediately downloaded on his computer after running the app.

This is what I have until now:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/excel")
def pdf_to_excel(date):
    index=0
    image= pdf_fix(image_path,index) #if the file is a pdf it turns into image
    words,output= text_extr(image) #outputs some words
    df= df_claims(words) #words become a dataframe
    excel_out(df, title) #writes excel file
    
    r = make_response(title)
    
    return r
```

For more context, the last function is

```
def excel_out(df, title):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(title, engine="xlsxwriter")
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape

    column_settings = [{"header": column} for column in df.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns": column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)
    writer.close()
```

How can I ask the user to import "image_path" and "title" in order for the app to import the image/pdf, perform these functions on it and save an excel file within the same directory as "image_path" with a chosen name indicated by "title"?